# WOOKMARK Refresh Filter when new images are fetched via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, wookmark

I am using [WookMark](https://github.com/germanysbestkeptsecret/Wookmark-jQuery) to create a gallery with categories filter and ajax infinite scroll. Everything seems to be working fine, but when new items are loaded via ajax they aren't added on filters ..

You can check it out [here.](http://studio9.webmose.com/)

My JS code is given

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // GET THE WINDOW WIDTH
    function getWindowWidth() {
      return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
    }

    // Initialize lightbox
    $('#container').magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'li:not(.inactive) a',
      type: 'image',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      }
    });

    // Instantiate wookmark after all images have been loaded
    var wookmark,
        container = '#container',
        $container = $(container),
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document);

    // init wookmark
    imagesLoaded('#container', function() {
      wookmark = new Wookmark('#container', {
        itemWidth: 300, // Optional min width of a grid item
        outerOffset: 0, // Optional the distance from grid to parent
        flexibleWidth: function () {
          // Return a maximum width depending on the viewport
          return getWindowWidth() < 1024 ? '100%' : '50%';
        }
      });
    });

    // INFINITE SCROLL
    // AJAX LOAD MORE
    $('#main').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('#main .load-more');
    var page = 2;
    var loading = false;
    var scrollHandling = {
        allow: true,
        reallow: function() {
            scrollHandling.allow = true;
        },
        delay: 400 //(milliseconds) adjust to the highest acceptable value
    };

    // Load more items on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if( ! loading && scrollHandling.allow ) {

        scrollHandling.allow = false;
        setTimeout(scrollHandling.reallow, scrollHandling.delay);
        var offset = $(button).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

        if( 2000 > offset ) {
          console.log('Added more items');
          // Get Next Page Posts AJAX
          loading = true;
          var data = {
            action: 'be_ajax_load_more',
            nonce: beloadmore.nonce,
            page: page,
            query: beloadmore.query,
          };
          $.post(beloadmore.url, data, function(res) {
            if( res.success) {
              // Get the first then items from the grid, clone them, and add them to the bottom of the grid
              var $items = $(res.data, $container);
              $container.append($items);

              wookmark.initItems();
              wookmark.layout(true, function () {
                // Fade in items after layout
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $items.css('opacity', 1);
                }, 300);
              });

              $('#main').append( button );
              page = page + 1;
              loading = false;
            } else {
              // console.log(res);
            }
          }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, e) {
            // console.log(xhr.responseText);
          });
        }
      }
    });

    // Setup filter buttons when jQuery is available
    var $filters = $('#filters li');

    /**
     * When a filter is clicked, toggle it's active state and refresh.
     */
    var onClickFilter = function(event) {
      updateFilterClasses();
      var $item = $(event.currentTarget),
          itemActive = $item.hasClass('active');

      if (!itemActive) {
        $filters.removeClass('active');
        itemActive = true;
      } else {
        itemActive = false;
      }
      $item.toggleClass('active');

      // Filter by the currently selected filter
      wookmark.filter(itemActive ? [$item.data('filter')] : []);
    }

    // Capture filter click events.
    $('#filters').on('click.wookmark-filter', 'li', onClickFilter);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I tracked the solution on Wookmark documentation ..

I have to update the filter classes when I load new items via ajax. So I simply added `wookmark.updateFilterClasses();` on my ajax success. Below is the working code if anyone needs it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function getWindowWidth() {
      return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
    }

     // Init lightbox
    $('#container').magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'li:not(.inactive) a',
      type: 'image',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      }
    });

    // Instantiate wookmark after all images have been loaded
    var wookmark,
        container = '#container',
        $container = $(container),
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document);

    imagesLoaded('#container', function() {
      wookmark = new Wookmark('#container', {
        itemWidth: 300, // Optional min width of a grid item
        outerOffset: 0, // Optional the distance from grid to parent
        flexibleWidth: function () {
          // Return a maximum width depending on the viewport
          return getWindowWidth() < 1024 ? '100%' : '50%';
        }
      });
    });

    $('#main').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('#main .load-more');
    var page = 2;
    var loading = false;
    var scrollHandling = {
        allow: true,
        reallow: function() {
            scrollHandling.allow = true;
        },
        delay: 400 //(milliseconds) adjust to the highest acceptable value
    };

    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if( ! loading && scrollHandling.allow ) {

        scrollHandling.allow = false;
        setTimeout(scrollHandling.reallow, scrollHandling.delay);
        var offset = $(button).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

        if( 2000 > offset ) {
          console.log('Added more items');
          // Get Next Page Posts AJAX
          loading = true;
          var data = {
            // Function which grabs next 10 posts available
            action: 'be_ajax_load_more',
            nonce: beloadmore.nonce,
            page: page,
            query: beloadmore.query,
          };
          $.post(beloadmore.url, data, function(res) {
            if( res.success) {
              // Get the first then items from the grid, clone them, and add them to the bottom of the grid
              var $items = $(res.data, $container);
              $container.append($items);

              wookmark.initItems();
              wookmark.updateFilterClasses();
              wookmark.layout(true, function () {
                // Fade in items after layout
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $items.css('opacity', 1);
                }, 300);
              });

              $('#main').append( button );
              page = page + 1;
              loading = false;
            } else {
              // console.log(res);
            }
          }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, e) {
            // console.log(xhr.responseText);
          });
        }
      }
    });

    // Setup filter buttons when jQuery is available
    var $filters = $('#filters li');

    /**
     * When a filter is clicked, toggle it's active state and refresh.
     */
    var onClickFilter = function(event) {
      var $item = $(event.currentTarget),
          itemActive = $item.hasClass('active');
      console.log(itemActive);

      if (!itemActive) {
        $filters.removeClass('active');
        itemActive = true;
      } else {
        itemActive = false;
      }
      $item.toggleClass('active');

      // Filter by the currently selected filter
      wookmark.filter(itemActive ? [$item.data('filter')] : []);
    }

    // Capture filter click events.
    $('#filters').on('click.wookmrk-filter', 'li', onClickFilter);

});
```